# Does arcing occur if nothing is plugged into the outlet?

Tags: electrical

Lets say you've installed a new wall outlet, and the hot or neutral, or both wires, inside the outlet are loosely connected.

Will arcing occur all the time, or only when an appliance is plugged in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arcing - electrical current flowing across an air gap - only occurs when there's an electrical potential - a voltage - between the material on either side of the gap.

You can get arcing in loose electrical connections, such as between the wire loop and the screw terminal on a receptacle.  This is considered a series arc - the gap is in series with the circuit.

A series arc will only occur in your example when there's a potential between the screw and the wire.  There is only a potential present if there's a load on the circuit - when something's turned on and running.

A parallel arc could occur when there's nothing plugged in.  If there was weak contact or near-contact between hot and neutral in the box that would create a parallel arc.  That can happen with a skinned hot wire touching the metal box, for example.  (If the contact is reasonably solid, there would be no air gap, and it will create a dead short, which should trip the breaker or blow the fuse quickly.)

Answer (score 2):

Outlets with only two power wires are failry rare.

If it's a midspan outlet and is serving as a junction appliances connected downstream pass current through the connections to the outlet, and loose connections then can cause overheaing and arcing

Answer (score 1):

Do **NOT** leave wires or terminals loose.

If any load is applied this can cause overheating possibly a fire.

If you are not sure of the skills to do work like this, do get it checked by a professional for safety.

Comment: Hi, thanks sure! But still, I'm not saying if I intentionally letting the wires loose, but by accident they've gone loose. Does arching still occur if there are only two wires and nothing is plugged in!